# Update table row with certain id while deleting the recurrent row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables

Table name: `Attributes`

```
attribute_id  |   attribute_name

    1               attr_name_1
    2               attr_name_2
    3               attr_name_1
    4               attr_name_2
```

Table name: `Products`

```
product_id    |   product_name    |    attribute_id
    1              prod_name_1              1
    2              prod_name_2              2
    3              prod_name_3              3
    4              prod_name_4              4
```

If you can see, `attribute_id` in the table `Products` has the following id's `(1,2,3,4)`, instead of `(1,2,1,2)`.

The problem is in the table `Attributes`, namely, there are repeating values(`attribute_names`) with different ID, so I want:

1. To pick One ID of the repeating, from the table `Attributes`
2. Update the table `Products` with that *"picked"* ID(only in cases that `attribute_id` has same name in the table `Attributes`)
3. And after that, delete the repeating values from the table `Attributes` witch has no use in the table `Products`

***Output:***

Table name: `Attributes`

```
attribute_id  |   attribute_name
     1              attr_name_1
     2              attr_name_2
```

Table name: `Products`

```
product_id    |   product_name    |    attribute_id
     1             prod_name_1              1
     2             prod_name_2              2
     3             prod_name_3              1
     4             prod_name_4              2
```

**Demo** on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fd342)

*Note:*

*it will help me a lot if i use sql instead fixing this issue manually.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
update Products
set attribute_id = (
    select min(attribute_id)
    from Attributes a
    where a.attribute_name=(select attribute_name from Attributes a2 where a2.attribute_id=Products.attribute_id)
);


DELETE
FROM Attributes
WHERE attribute_id NOT IN
(
    SELECT MIN(attribute_id)
    FROM Attributes
    GROUP BY attribute_name
);
```

Comment: I get this error: 

`Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'attribute_id', table 'dbo.Products'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.`

Comment: Hmmm...please try `update Products
set attribute_id = (
    select min(attribute_id)
    from Attributes a
    where ISNULL(a.attribute_name,'emptyname')=(select ISNULL(attribute_name,'emptyname') from Attributes a2 where a2.attribute_id=Products.attribute_id)
);`

Answer (score 1):

The following may be faster than [@Alexander Sigachov's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17085863/297408), but it does require at least SQL Server 2005 to run it, while Alexander's solution would work on *any* (reasonable) version of SQL Server. Still, even if only for the sake of providing an alternative, here you go:

```
WITH Min_IDs AS (
  SELECT
    attribute_id,
    min_attribute_id = MIN(attribute_id) OVER (PARTITION BY attribute_name)
  FROM Attributes
)
UPDATE p
SET    p.attribute_id = a.min_attribute_id
FROM   Products p
JOIN   Min_IDs  a ON a.attribute_id = p.attribute_id
WHERE  a.attribute_id <> a.min_attribute_id
;

DELETE FROM Attributes
WHERE attribute_id NOT IN (
  SELECT attribute_id
  FROM   Products
  WHERE  attribute_id IS NOT NULL
)
;
```

The first statement's [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) returns a row set where every `attribute_id` is mapped to the minimum `attribute_id` for the same `attribute_name`. By joining to this mapping set, the `UPDATE` statement uses it to replace `attribute_id`s in the `Products` table.

When subsequently deleting from `Attributes`, it is enough just to check if `Attributes.attribute_id` is not found in the `Products.attribute_id` column, which is what the the second statement does. That is to say, grouping and aggregation, as in the other answer, is not needed at this point.

The `WHERE attribute_id IS NOT NULL` condition is added to the second query's subquery in case the column is nullable and may indeed contain NULLs. NULLs need to be filtered out in this case, or their presence would result in the `NOT IN` predicate's evaluation to `UNKNOWN`, which SQL Server would treat same as `FALSE` (and so *no* row would effectively be deleted). If there cannot be NULLs in `Products.attribute_id`, the condition may be dropped.